# Migrate module only imports first line of CSV file

Tags: users, migrations

I have a Migrate module class that works with CSV files and when I go through with the import it only goes through the first line of the CSV and then completes with a success message.  That one line is imported correctly and the data is in place, but I'm wondering why it continues to stop at the first line.

When I run the import again it does not import anything and completes with success message again, mostly likely because the first line is already imported.

Any ideas?

```
class UserMigration extends MyMigration {
  public function __construct($arguments) {
    parent::__construct($arguments);

    $this->description = t('Import Users');
    $columns = array(
      0 => array('username', 'Username'),
      2 => array('email', 'Email'),
    );

    $this->source = new MigrateSourceCSV(drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module') . '/Users.csv', $columns);
    $this->destination = new MigrateDestinationUser();
    $this->addFieldMapping('name', 'username');
    $this->addFieldMapping('mail', 'email');
    $this->addFieldMapping('roles')
         ->defaultValue(DRUPAL_AUTHENTICATED_RID);
    $source_key = array(
      'username' => array(
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'length' => 255,
        'not null' => TRUE,
      )
    );
    $this->map = new MigrateSQLMap($this->machineName, $source_key, MigrateDestinationUser::getKeySchema());

  }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that the CSV is saved with line endings in the wrong format? Be default, I think Migrate expects Unix format.

Comment: @DaveBruns I believe that would be culprit.  I've been having issues with these CSVs as they are saved from Server '03 and I'm on a Mac.  I will re-generate the files on this machine and try again.

Comment: @DaveBruns Re-generating the file with Uniux file endings worked perfectly.  You may want to make this an answer to the question so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that the CSV is saved with the wrong line endings. Try saving the CSV file with Unix-style line endings. By default, I believe Migrate expects a Unix format text file.